# Identity Server Authorization Code Flow example - Reading Claims

Tags: c#, identityserver4, identityserver3

I have implemented an Identity Provider and a client application using Code flow. When validating he token and going through the claims, I can;t find the claims associated with the user I am suing.
Code is very similar to [Identity Server 4 Authorization Code Flow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37309986/identity-server-4-authorization-code-flow-example/)

```
private IEnumerable<Claim> ValidateToken(string token)
{
    var certPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/bin"), "SscSign.pfx");
    var cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath);
    var x509SecurityKey = new X509SecurityKey(cert);

    var parameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                         {
                             RequireSignedTokens = true,
                             ValidAudience = audience,
                             ValidIssuer = validIssuer,
                             IssuerSigningKey = new X509SecurityKey(cert),
                             RequireExpirationTime = true,
                             ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
                         };

    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    SecurityToken jwt;
    var id = handler.ValidateToken(token, parameters, out jwt);

    foreach (Claim claim in id.Claims)
    {
        **I can't see any claim for key email**
    }

    this.Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut("TempCookie");

    return id.Claims;
}
```

I would appreciate it if anyone can help me read the email claim. @bayardw

Comment: Maybe show us what you have sofar and we can actually help. The text "It doesn't work" doesn't help us figuring out your problem.

Comment: Edited the question with more detail. As you can see in the example user has email claim but I can't see it in the list of claims.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you don't have a claim with email.
You can check it here [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/)

You have to define it in settings for Resources [docs.identityserver.io](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/resources.html)