# SSO for IdentityServer4 with grant type "authorization_code"

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4

We're in a scenario where a single page application that we develop ourselves (AngularJS front end with https server APIs in the back) opens another
web application developed by a partner of ours in a new browser tab, and where this second web application needs access to a https server API that is also developed by us.

After looking around for possible solutions, we have now created a proof of concept using IdentityServer4, where the second web application is configured as a client with "authorization_code" grant type. When all applications are running on the same domain, the third party application is able to access our https server API without being prompted for user id and password.

The implementation of the second web application in this proof of concept is very much like the solution presented by bayardw for the post

[Identity Server 4 Authorization Code Flow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37309986/identity-server-4-authorization-code-flow-example)

My question now is:

When - in production - the second web application no longer shares domain with our application and our https server API, will a call from the second web application be prompted for username and password when accessing our http server API?

Answer (score 0):

Seems, you are missing some major things. 
First of all any API should never ask for username and password. Instead your app(s) should put a token into each request and API should validate that token. Where the user credentials should be asked is when a user accesses your (or 3-rd party) web application. Then Identity Provider creates an Identity token (usually to be persisted in a cookie and used within the app) and access token (to be provided to APIs). 
Each token is issued for specific Client (app) pre-registered in IdP. 
Probably when been hosted at the same domain your two apps shared the identity cookie and Client Id what is not correct. 
In production scenario you have to register the apps separately. All the rest should work fine (if you follow the routine i briefly described at the beginning).

Comment: Thanks d_f for your answer. It is clear that from my short problem description, you are left to assume on various aspects of my solution. However, I do not think that I am doing that much wrong , as I can say "check" to your described solution. Robert Broeckelmann, who has great posts on this on medium.com, points out that this boils down to the session tracking of the IdP, and I will proceed from there. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, as you wanted to know some different thing than what you asked about, then yes, nobody could answer better than you : ) Anyway if your'e utilizing IdSrv as your IdP, it could be simper to start reading it's documentation to study the possible options, configuration and extension points. Robert Broeckelmann's posts are great, but maybe too complicated for the very beginning, and some stuff he describes such as Single sign-out options has not enough support in IdSrv and require additional coding.

Answer (score 0):

Chosing to post an answer myself from feedback through other channels:

This boils down to the session tracking of the IdP. If cookies are being used to track IdP session, the behavior is impacted by whether a session cookie or a persistent cookie is used.

In general, I have found that Robert Broeckelmann has great articles on medium.com.